# Perl assignment with a dummy placeholder

Tags: perl, split

In other languages I've used like Erlang and Python, if I am splitting a string and don't care about one of the fields, I can use an underscore placeholder.  I tried this in Perl:

```
   (_,$id) = split('=',$fields[1]);
```

But I get the following error:

> Can't modify constant item in list assignment at ./generate_datasets.pl line 17, near ");"
>   Execution of ./generate_datasets.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Does Perl have a similar such pattern that I could use instead of creating a useless temporary variables?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`undef` serves the same purpose in Perl.

```
(undef, $something, $otherthing) = split(' ', $str);
```

Comment: Note: even valid in a declaration `my (undef, $a, $b) = ...`

Answer (score 18):

You don't even need placeholders if you use [Slices](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html#Slices):

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my ($id) = (split /=/, 'foo=id123')[1];
print "$id\n";

__END__

id123
```

Answer (score 9):

You can assign to `(undef)`.

```
(undef, my $id) = split(/=/, $fields[1]);
```

You can even use `my (undef)`.

```
my (undef, $id) = split(/=/, $fields[1]);
```

You could also use a list slice.

```
my $id = ( split(/=/, $fields[1]) )[1];
```

Answer (score 3):

And just to explain why you get the particular error that you see...

`_` is a internal Perl variable that can be used in the `stat` command to indicate "the same file as we used in the previous `stat` call". That way Perl uses a cached stat data structure and doesn't make another `stat` call.

```
if (-x $file and -r _) { ... }
```

This filehandle is a constant value and can't be written to. The variable is stored in the same typeglob as `$_` and `@_`.

See [perldoc stat](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html).