# Throwaway variables in multiple assignment

Tags: perl

Let's say I have a function `foo` which returns a fixed-length list, and I assign the returned list to a handful of variables like so:

```
($duck, $lemonade, $stand, $grapes) = foo($waddle);
```

But then it turns out that I don't actually want `$lemonade`. I could replace it with the underscore to say that I don't need the value (it's used for this purpose in a few other programming languages), but since it has an implicit special meaning in Perl, I thought it might be anything from confusing to outright bad.

Does Perl have a convention for such "throwaway" variables, or is there a more Perly (perlish?) way of doing this? Or rather, given this is Perl, what other ways are there?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917094/perl-assignment-with-a-dummy-placeholder just came up on related questions and answers this question exactly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this to be explicit about which values you are throwing away:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub foo {
    return ( 1..4 );
}

my ( $one, undef, $three, undef ) = foo();

print "$one $three\n"; # prints "1 3"
```

Comment: second undef isn't actually needed

Comment: Right, but it does make it clear that you haven't accidentally ignored it.