# Ruby: Discarding Variables from Multiple Assignment from Array

Tags: ruby

For the given variable assignment from array:

```
a,b,c,d,e = [ "foo","bar","discard","discard","blah" ]
```

Is there a way to only have `a`, `b`, and `e` assigned and discard `c` and `d`? Is there an `undef` like in perl ([Perl assignment with a dummy placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917094/perl-assignment-with-a-dummy-placeholder)).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

```
a,b,_,_,e = [ "foo","bar","discard","discard","blah" ]
```

Comment: As far as I understand, _ is just a standard variable? Is it any difference than using any arbitrary variable? ```a,b,undefined,undefined,e``` ?

Comment: @PressingOnAlways `_` is just another variable name. It's typically used to denote a variable that is not used (for example, when you need to provide a block that takes a parameter which you don't need).

Comment: I see, so it is just used by convention, but not necessarily a special reserved identifier like in perl.

Comment: The `_` does not result in warnings about unused variables (when run with warnings enabled; `ruby -w`)

Comment: Sometimes it's convenient to capture some values in an array. For example, `a,b,*c,e = ["foo", "bar", "discard", "discard", "blah" ]`, `c #=> ["discard", "discard"] `.

Comment: @PressingOnAlways: The [`_` variable (and any others with a leading underscore as of Ruby 2.0) is treated specially](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9560198/479863) by Ruby specifically for throw-away cases like this.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the *splat* operator.

```
 a,b,*,e = ["foo","bar",nil,nil,"blah"]
```

Comment: I haven't seen this use before. Interesting.

Answer (score 1):

If the array is longish, this is an alternative:

```
a,b,e = [ "foo","bar","discard","discard","blah" ].values_at(0,1,4)
```